# MySQL - Marking duplicates from several table fields, as well as data from another table

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables - one shows user purchases, and one shows a product id with it's corresponding product type.

My client wants to make duplicate users inactive based on last name and email address, but wants to run the query by product type (based on what type of product they purchased), and only wants to include user_ids who haven't purchased paint (product ids 5 and 6). So the query will be run multiple times - once for all people who have purchased lawnmowers, and then for all people who have purchased leafblowers etc (and there will be some overlap between these two). No user_id that has purchased paint should be made inactive.

In terms of who should stay active among the duplicates, the one to stay active will be the one with the highest product id purchased (as products are released annually). If they have multiple records with the same product id, the record to stay active will be the one with most recent d_modified and t_modified.

I also want to shift the current value of 'inactive' to the 'previously_inactive' column, so that this can be easily reversed if need be.

Here is some sample table data

[image]

If the query was run by leafblower purchases, rows 5, 6, and 7 would be made inactive. This is the expected output:

[image]

If the query was run by lawnmower purchases, rows 1 and 2 would be made inactive. This would be the expected output:

[image]

If row 4 was not the most recent, it would still not be made inactive, as user_id 888 had bought paint (and we want to exclude these user_ids from being made inactive).

This is an un-optimised version of the query for 'leafblower' purchases (it is working, but will probably be too slow in the interface):

```
UPDATE test.user_purchases
SET inactive = 1
WHERE id IN (
    SELECT z.id
    FROM (SELECT * FROM test.user_purchases) z
    WHERE z.product_id IN (
        SELECT product_id
        FROM test.products
        WHERE product_type IN ("leafblower")
    )
    AND id NOT IN (
        SELECT a.id
        FROM (SELECT * FROM test.user_purchases) a
        INNER JOIN (
            SELECT r.surname, r.email
            FROM (SELECT * FROM test.user_purchases) r
            JOIN test.products s on r.product_id = s.product_id
            WHERE s.product_type IN ("paint")
        ) b
        WHERE a.surname = b.surname
        AND a.email = b.email
    )
    AND id NOT IN (
        SELECT MAX(z.id)
        FROM (SELECT * FROM test.user_purchases) z
        WHERE z.product_id IN (
            SELECT product_id
            FROM test.products
            WHERE product_type IN ("leafblower")
        )
        AND id NOT IN (
            SELECT a.id
            FROM (SELECT * FROM test.user_purchases) a
            INNER JOIN (
                SELECT r.surname, r.email
                FROM (SELECT * FROM test.user_purchases) r
                JOIN test.products s on r.product_id = s.product_id
                WHERE s.product_type IN ("paint")
            ) b
            WHERE a.surname = b.surname
            AND a.email = b.email
        )
        GROUP BY surname, email
    )
)
```

Any suggestions on how I can streamline this query and optimise the speed of it would be much appreciated.

Comment: You haven't gotten a response, and I'm not surprised, because your question is not very clear.  Please _edit_ your question, and show clear sample table data as _text_, not as an image.  Then, show the expected output.  If you just do this, you will be conveying the basic idea of your question.

Comment: Also, if there a columns which are irrelevant to the problem, don't include in them in the problem.

Comment: Have edited to show expected output. There wasn't enough space for text tables, hence the use of images.